# Fragment activity calls on destroy method when i navigate from fragment activity to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

in my application, onDestroy function of fragmentactivity will get called if i move from one fragment to another activity.

in my application, there is a listfragment and a slidingmenu fragment. Now if i click on any item of listfragment onDestroy function of fragment activity will get called.

If i press backbutton, my fragment objects will be NULL, why so? what needs to be done in this case.
Here is my full code

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setBehindContentView(R.layout.left_options_menu);

    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_list_items);

    if (findViewById(R.id.id_list_options_menu) != null) {

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {

        mOptionsFragment = new LeftSliderListOptions();
        mListFragment = new GTasksFragment();

        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();//create an instance of Fragment-transaction

        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.id_task_list_options_menu, mOptionsFragment, "optionfragment");
        transaction.add(R.id.id_list_fragment, mListFragment, "mainlistfragment");
        transaction.commit();

    }
    }


    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setFadeEnabled(false);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);


}



    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
         super.onDestroy();

    }
```

How to save and reuse the existing fragment objects?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are few reason why your onDestroy method will be called on moving from one fragment to another activity

http://www.androidoutput.com/2014/03/android-activity-ondestroy-called-always.html.

It could be killed by your android OS to free memory, you might be calling finish or check your phone developer settings.